# Please explain me this code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
rez = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
```

I am not able to understand how it will print the transpose when we use it in for loop . Can someone explain the working thoroughly ?

Comment: what is `m`? a numpy array?

Comment: M is an array of 3*2 order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Parakh, you did not specify what m is, so I made it a 2d array:

```
m = [[6, 2], 
     [3, 4]]

rez = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
print(rez)
```

## [[6, 3], [2, 4]]

This is the same as:

````
```
m = [[6, 2], 
     [3, 4]]

rez = []
for i in range(len(m[0])):
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(m)):
        temp.append(m[j][i])
    rez.append(temp)
print(rez)
```
````

This is producing column 0, row 0 (6) and column 0, row 1 (3) as the first new list,
then column 1, row 0 (2) and column 1, row 1 (4) as the second new list.

j is the row index, i is the column index.

```
i[0], j[0] = 6
i[0], j[1] = 3 
i[1], j[0] = 2
i[1], j[1] = 4
```